# Get VideoUri from DocumentFile

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm selecting the folder from Gallery using following piece of code and it is returning me uri which i use to retrieve all the files in that directory.

```
 private void folderExplorer() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

 private void fetchAllFiles() {
        videoList.clear();
        try {
            // sample uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATestVideos    
            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri.parse(mySharedPreferences.getFolderName()));

            // List all existing files inside picked directory    
            DocumentFile childFile[] = pickedDir.listFiles();    
                for (DocumentFile file : childFile) {
                        Video video = new Video();
                        video.setFileName(file.getName());
                        video.setFilePath(file.getUri().toString());
                        videoList.add(video);
                }
                populateList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Above mentioned code is working fine, the issue only exists when i try to set Uri in VideoView then it doesn't play:

```
 'holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));'
```

// video uri sample:

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ATestVideos/document/primary%3ATestVideos%2F7862%20-%20Copy%20(4).mp4`

Comment: setVideoURI() probably expects a file uri. Not a content scheme uri.

Comment: `/ video uri sample: ` What you posted is the value for videoPath i think. Is it equal to video.getFilePath() ? What kind of videoView is this?

Comment: yes, it is video.getFilePath()  and it is passed after proper uri parsing.

Comment: `it is passed after proper uri paring` ??? Where are you talking about? You better had given an exaple from onActivityResult() whith        `DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, data.getData());`. Why would you bother us with shared preferences? Post reproducable code please.

Comment: `setVideoURI() probably expects a file uri. Not a content scheme uri. `. You did not react on this. I wonder why. Please confirm or deny.

Comment: you can see at the above line of sharedpreferences , i've pasted a sample uri as well. And if i'm able to check the existence of file at that path. But, it is unable to play in VideoView

Comment: `And if i'm able to check the existence of file at that path.` What do you mean with checking existence? Yo got that uri from listFiles() so the file will exist. There is no code posted that checks the existence. But why would you?

Comment: `setVideoURI() probably expects a file uri. Not a content scheme uri. . You did not react on this. I wonder why. Please confirm or deny.`